# How to implement authentication to asp.net mvc 4 application using identity provider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application "APP1" which has Entity Framework implemented using the DB First approach. I now want to add Authentication to it, **including email and roles**, and if I get this right, the state-of-the-art approach for doing this is using identity provider. What I tried is to make a new mvc 4 web application "APP2" and adding the automatically generated `Account-model, -views and -controller` to my existing "APP1"-application and extending the AccountModel with an additional EmailAdress property:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

I also added the Label and TextBox for the Email Address to the Register.cshtml View:

```
<li>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
</li>
```

So far so good. But when running the WepApp and trying to load the `/Account/Register` View, it throws me an error, it occurs in `Filter/InitializeSimpleMembershipAttributes.cs`:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   NetradoxDotCom.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could
>   not be initialized. For more information, please see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588

How can I solve that problem? Also, How can I enable user roles, e.g. admin?

**UPDATE 1**
I solved it, the login page's working now! What I did was commenting the `DefaultConnection` ConnectionString out at the `web.config` file:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-APP1-20131105213440;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-APP1-20131105213440.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

So far, so good, but is it also possible to use my EF SQL Server Instance instead? Also, what's the easiest way to make roles?

**UPDATE 2**
I was able to change the DB by changing the `DefaultConnection` ConnectionString at the `web.config` file.

Thank you

Comment: Post your code of your Identity framework data context which is inheriting from IdentityDbContext class, have you bind the models as you are using db first approach?

Comment: Not sure if I get you right, but I think they're bound since the models are being generated by EF. Do you need the whole Code, all of it? its 800 lines..

Comment: I know what you mean by 800 lines, but it is your data context for whole database, I assume that part of class inherited from DbContext isn't it? I mean the part for your identity framework database tables which should be inherited from IdentityDbContext, not DbContext.

Comment: Well, all of the models I have are generated by the EF, except the AccountModel. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I think maybe it would be a good idea for you to look at the template that comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: well as I said, what I did was copying all those files from the template site to my existing mvc4 application. but that didn't do the trick for me